# Setting BorderBrush in code on TextBox and DatePicker

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two questions that you hopefully can help me with:

1. I'm struggeling with BorderBrush property and I need to be able to set it in code. It works if I do it like below but I need to give it a haxadecimal value (#ffcccccc) and can't figure out how to do it.

   datePicker1.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
2. I have a datePicker and would like to give it a border color and set the background in the same way as my TextBox fields but I'm failing. What is the trick in modifying this control? I would prefer if I didn't have to use Blend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb.aspx)
2. You have to customize the DatePicker template. This is of course, easiest done using Expression Blend. If you're clueless about XAML, I'll recommend you don't do custom control styles unless you have studied the subject more.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I can use Blend but prefer not to, but now I know that's the only way :)

Comment: I gave it a try in Expression Blend and it was really easy. So thanks once again!